# How to get exact result from JOIN SQL queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I wrote one SQL query which runs only on SQL-Server. Unfortunately, I am not getting my desired result. It is a LEFT JOIN Query. I am expecting distinct value only, but getting duplicate value, that I don't want. I have also used  `SELECT DISTINCT` and `Group BY`, but it didn't work properly. Can anyone please guide me what would be the right query for below SQL?

The SQL query:

```
USE smileTour; 

SELECT 
  travelCountrySet.CountryID,
  travelOffer.OfferID,                  
  travelCountry.CountryName         
FROM travelOffer
LEFT JOIN travelCountrySet ON travelOffer.OfferID = travelCountrySet.OfferID
LEFT JOIN travelCountry ON travelCountry.CountryID = travelCountrySet.CountryID
WHERE  travelOffer.Active = 1
```

Tables are respectively travelOffer, travel country and travelCountrySet. The key point is that travelCountrySet table has two column field OfferID and CountryID by which travelOffer and travelCountry can be connected. So that I made the LEFT JOIN which was not the desire result. And the result is

```
=====================================================
    CountryID----OfferID----CountryName
1 ---- 4     ----  1    ----  A 
2 ---- 15    ----  1    ----  B 
3 ---- 4     ----  2    ----  C
4 ---- 11    ----  4    ----  D
5 ---- 4     ----  5    ----  E
6 ---- 15    ----  5    ----  F
7 ---- 11    ----  6    ----  G
8 ---- 15    ----  7    ----  H
```

Here is showing 8 rows, but I want only 7 rows because I have only 7 offers.  Above result is showing OfferId 1 is two times and OfferId 5 is two time. I need only one time each.

Thanks for your support!.

Comment: Well....you have CountryName in your query and you have this offer available in more than 1 country. Either remove that column or decide which row you want. MAX, MIN, whatever. You don't have distinct values so of course no grouping or distinct will "fix" this. Your life would be easier if you got in the habit of using aliases so you don't have to type so much.

Comment: If the same offer is available in multiple countries, how do you possibly expect this to be distinct?

Comment: @SeanLange I can't remove the CountryName. The challenge is to get the distinct values. I have used as well as aliases but does not work.

Comment: @Jacobm001 This is the question that I could not understand as well as, so that I asked.

Comment: I provided a couple of ways to aggregate the countries to get distinct offer IDs. If this is not what you are looking for, then please provide the desired output.

Comment: @Riyad: Your  question doesn't make sense from a logical point of view. What you have received *is* the distinct values. It's not the distinct offers, but including the location makes the offers non distinct.

Comment: @Riyad: This will be very easy to solve I suppose. All you have to do is show the result you want. So far we see the the eight rows you get. Now please show the six rows you want instead.

Comment: You have completed the challenge. You have the distinct rows returned in your query. Unless you can explain what you expect as output this question unanswerable.

Comment: @SeanLange Simply I have 1 offer that has multiple country. Like Offer 1 should be Countryid 1 and Country id 2 and so on. Like this is output `CountryID----OfferID----CountryName 4 ,15 ---- 1 ---- A ,B <br> 4 ---- 2 ---- C<br> 11 ---- 4 ---- D<br> 4,15 ---- 5 ---- E,F<br> 11 ---- 6 ---- G<br> 15 ---- 7 ---- H`

Comment: Please don't put details in the comments. As you can see they don't format well. But from the sample output you showed us you have multiple countries for an offer which is why you have multiple rows. You need to provide us some data that represents your problem. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to review [the distinct function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp). It will return unique rows. Since you are showing the Country name which is different for the same offerID, you are receiving distinct rows. It will return every unique combination of the columns selected (offerID 1 country 1 & offerID 1 country 2 are 2 distinct rows).

If you want distinct offers then you will need to determine how you want to aggregate the countries. Here you have 6 distinct offers, likely because travelOffer.Active = 1 is false for OfferID 3. If there is a maximum number of countries you expect to be linked to an offer, then you can [pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) it and have a column for each country, or you could have a count of countries, but as long as you list each country in a new row and you have at least one offer with more than one country, you will not have distinct OfferIDs.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/298694/19/0) is the SQL Fiddle I did for this

You can try this to get a list of offers and the number of countries for them:

```
SELECT 
  travelOffer.OfferID,
  COUNT(travelCountrySet.CountryID) AS country_count,
FROM travelOffer
LEFT JOIN travelCountrySet ON travelOffer.OfferID = travelCountrySet.OfferID
LEFT JOIN travelCountry ON travelCountry.CountryID = travelCountrySet.CountryID
WHERE  travelOffer.Active = 1
GROUP BY travelOffer.OfferID
```

If you have an upper limit of countries per offer you can use a pivot as well. This will only list up to 4 countries (update as needed):

```
SELECT
  OfferID,
  [1] AS Country1,
  [2] AS Country2,
  [3] AS Country3,
  [4] AS Country4
FROM(
  SELECT
    travelOffer.OfferID,
    travelCountry.CountryName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY travelOffer.OfferID ORDER BY travelCountry.CountryName) AS rn
  FROM travelOffer
  LEFT JOIN travelCountrySet ON
    travelOffer.OfferID = travelCountrySet.OfferID
  LEFT JOIN travelCountry ON
travelCountrySet.CountryID = travelCountry.CountryID
  WHERE  travelOffer.Active = 1
  ) AS source_table
  PIVOT
  (
    MAX(CountryName)
    FOR rn IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
  ) AS pivot_table
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew, 
Thanks for the Multi solutions, I thought that first solution would be relevant for my problem. Unfortunately it doesn't work, Simply I have 1 offer that has multiple country. Like Offer 1 should be Countryid 1 and Country id 2 and so on. 


`CountryID----OfferID----CountryName
 4 ,15     ----  1    ----  A ,B <br>
 4     ----  2    ----  C<br>
 11    ----  4    ----  D<br>
 4,15     ----  5    ----  E,F<br>
 11    ----  6    ----  G<br>
 15    ----  7    ----  H`

Comment: You can achieve that by concatenating the country_id and country columns after pivoting.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew it's helped me lots

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct. Offer ID 1 is found in 2 countries and hence this -you either need to accept it as it is or use an aggregate function to select the first/last country where this offer is available . A join is supposed to give results for all matching keys , hence this is already an EXACT result  . You can tweak the queries to get the desired output(getting an offer once only).